# Deny direct access except for the files and subdirectories with rewritten urls without file types

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, restriction

How can I prevent users from accessing a directory directly without preventing the files and sub directories being accessed? Please note that all my pages are written in php and the file type `.php` is omitted using htaccess url rewrites.

When I tried to attain waht I need using the following htaccess lines, I get 403 errors for all my url's, as they do not have a file type in them.

```
# Deny access to everything by default
Order Deny,Allow
deny from all

# Allow access to html files
<Files *.*>
    allow from all
</Files>
```

The `.htaccess` file is in the `dir` folder

When try to access `http://www.domain.com/dir/sub/page` I get a 403 error. But when I try to access `http://www.domain.com/dir/sub/page.php` (note the `.php` file type) everything works fine. How can I restrict the prohibition ONLY to DIRECTORIES, with respect to my rewrite rules?

I need to restrict direct access *only to directories and sub directories*. I need to access whatever the *flies* inside the directories and sub directories.

Related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17611770/1609555) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7921757/1609555) did not help me since the *omission of file type* was not applicable to those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `I need to restrict direct access only to directories and sub directories. I need to access whatever the flies inside the directories and sub directories.`
>
> `What I meant was to prohibit directory listing. And show to 403 instead`

You can try following rule:

```
# disable directory listing
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Well, I still *can* access the files when I access `/dir/page.php`, but not when I access `dir/page`

Comment: But you wanted to restrict directory access only and want to access files inside?

Comment: What I meant was to prohibit directory listing. And show to 403 instead

Comment: Just to disable directory listing all you need is `Options -Indexes` Take out my suggested rule.